# Was there an uncredited Adam Sandler cameo in Doctor Who: The Big Bang (S5 E13)

Tags: doctor-who, cameo

I'm not sure if this is episode is new enough to warrant a spoiler block, but because it's the series finale, I'll add one anyway.

In Doctor Who series 5 episode 13: [The Big Bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Bang_%28Doctor_Who%29), At

> Amy and Rory's wedding, after Amy jumps on the table and starts yelling about remembering the Doctor

The camera pans across the faces of several stunned guests.  One of the guests looks like Adam Sandler. [The full cast list for this episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1607759/fullcredits#cast) doesn't mention him at all.

Did he have an uncredited cameo?

Here's a screen capture of the scene I'm asking about:
[image]

Comment: That's __not__ Adam Sandler.

Comment: @Oliver_C That would be one of his best recent performances if it was.

Comment: It looks much more like Chris O'Dowd from The IT Crowd (see https://cultbox.co.uk/features/lists/top-10-episodes-of-the-it-crowd), although I can't see anything where he claims it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that Adam Sandler could have made a cameo in this episode as, on the day of filming (in [Swansea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brangwyn_Hall)) he was [hosting the 52nd Annual Grammy Awards](http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/news-photo/comedian-adam-sandler-onstage-during-the-52nd-annual-grammy-news-photo/180042265) (in Los Angeles).

[image]

I'll happily admit he could theoretically have jumped the [red-eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-eye_flight) (12.5 hours, not including transfers) and traveled to Wales to play a small role as an uncredited extra in a low-budget British scifi show, but that doesn't seem especially credible.

Comment: And it only took three years to get an answer with actual evidence. :)

Comment: @Kalamane - You should have asked me sooner :-)

Answer (score 17):

I don't really know how to prove it definitively, but it seems pretty clear to me that they're not the same guy when you look at the guy from your picture side by side with 2010 Adam Sandler.  I guess the most telling part is different head shape, the Dr Who guy has less of an oval shape to his noggin.

[image]

Comment: Adam Sandler has one eye higher than the other. The Dr Who extra does not.